# Fetching profile picture and name and etc. from Facebook by ID

Tags: php, html, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used this link in 2014 in php to fetching profile photo, name, surname and other information from Facebook by just ID number.
**http://graph.facebook.com/{ID}/** - this link returned me json encoded information and I can decode this and use. But now in 2016 this link does not work. It seems Facebook changed its graph structure, how I can use it now? With another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can get "me" (the user which authorized to your app) picture using javascript Graph API.

```js
FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"id,name,picture"},
  function(response) {
      console.log(picture.data.url);
  }
);
```

You can play with the Graph API in the facebook's tool [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cpicture&version=v2.7)

Read more about Graph API [javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart), [php](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Graph API Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog). Looks like you are using old v1.0 version of API. It's obsolete. To get user's public profile you should use [`/v2.7/{user-id}`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) URL.

More over, since v2.0 you can not get list of friends with default `public_profile` permission. Your app should also have `user_friends` permission.